# Binary search trees to count the number of full classes

Tags: scheme, binary-search-tree

I am using beginning language with list abbreviations

What I want my program to do is to consumes a BST (course) and a natural number (cap) and produce the classes
that are full. A class is considered full, if there are at least cap students enrolled in the class

this is what I have done so far :

A BST is either empty, or

```
(make-node Nat (listof Nat) BST BST),
```

which satisfies the ordering property recursively:

every course-id in left is less than course-id

every course-id in right is greater than course-id

requires:

10000 < course-id <= 99999

every element in studlist is between 100000000 and 999999999

inclusive, which represent the IDs of the students who are

enrolled in the course.

```
(define-struct node (key val left right))
```

helper function, which counts the number of students in a class :

```
(define (count-students alist)    
 (cond
    [(empty? alist) 0]

    [(cons? (car alist))(+(count-students(car alist))
                          (count-students(cdr alist)))]
            [else(+ 1(count-students(cdr alist)))]))
```

main function:

```
(define (count-full-courses courses cap)
 (cond
    [(empty? courses)0 ]

    [else (cond
             [(or (=(count-students(node-val courses))cap)
                  (>(count-students(node-val courses))cap))(add1(+
                                                              (count-full-courses (node-left courses)cap)
                                                              (count-full-courses (node-right courses)cap)))]
```

example of what should happen :

```
(define c89761 (make-node 89761 (list 987654321 673498453 237622334) empty empty))

(define c99800 (make-node 99800 (list 673498453 673498453 876542334 777777777)empty empty))

(define c99500 (make-node 99500 (list 987654321 673498453 673498453 876542334)empty c99800))

(define c99999 (make-node 99999 (list 987654321 673498453 444444444)c99500 empty))

(define DB     (make-node 99065 (list 123456789 987654321 673498453 876542334)c89761 c99999))

(count-full-courses DB 4) should produce 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I figured it out, I just needed a few more base cases.